# how to disable this document.getElementById("failedUpdateMessage").style.visibility = "hidden"; in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

after I used that code to hide the element with the id "failedUpdateMessage", I would like to show that hidden element in some page in html, how would I do that using java script? I'd try to replace the "hidden" to "show" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use :

```
 document.getElementById("failedUpdateMessage").style.visibility ="visible";
```

Note : show() works on elements hidden with jQuery methods and display:none in CSS (but not visibility:hidden).

Answer (score 2):

Look up [the visibility property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility). See what values are acceptable. Don't guess. `show` isn't one of them. `visible` is.